# Android XML configChanges tag has no effect

Tags: android, xml, opencv, android-configchanges

The

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

tag has no effect. My activity always is destroyed when the device is rotated. I do not know why this is. I have added every possible flag to the above and it still has no effect. Another relevant (?) fact: this activity contains an OpenCv JavaCameraView (camera 1 under the hood).

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mycompany.myname.mycamera">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Why might this tag not be having any effect?

e: I should specify: I want to prevent my activity from being destroyed on rotation, but I do want to know when a rotation occurs and what the current orientation is.

Comment: what is your requirement, Do you want to stop orientation of activity..

Comment: I want to prevent my activity from being destroyed on rotation, but I do want to know when a rotation occurs and what the current orientation is.

Comment: read this, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: How are you determining that the activity is being destroyed?

Comment: I just checked - the activity isn't actually being destroyed! However, my activity's layout completely changes on orientation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

For detecting orientation change:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I receive the onConfigurationChanged(), but the tag still has no effect.

Comment: It should work, even according to documentation it should, well I will see more then.